# Different scales on x/y axis in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I've been using Matlab to draw plots for reports I'm assigned. However, I don't know how to make the axis look [as shown in the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh8RP.png)

However, the data I'm using isn't a function, but a set of points. For example:

```
A=[714 743 879 943 1067 1116 1214];
B=[76 82 96 84 132 115 90];
semilogx(A,B)
axis square
axis([0 10000 50 150])
```

would create a graph with logarithimic x-axis, but without the values nor scale presented in the link.

I've tried using semilogx function or different arguments for plot function, but failed miserably. Setting the range for x/y axis also doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try setting the 'XTick' property? Also 'XLim' is useful.

Comment: Thank you! XTick was exactly what I needed to make it work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change xlim like this:

```
xlim(minmax(A))
```

You may also want to control which numbers show as Xtick

```
set(gca,'xtick',[800,1000,1200])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for if you want it to look exactly like your plot sample:

```
A=[714 743 879 943 1067 1116 1214];
B=[76 82 96 84 132 115 90];
semilogx(A,B,'k-o','MarkerFaceColor','k')
axis square

xlim([100,1e4])
xticks_points = logspace(log10(125),log10(8000),7);
xticks(xticks_points)

ylim([40,150])
yticks(50:10:140)
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

XLim and XTick with labels were enough to solve this problem.